# Objective-C unrecongnized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set the label that is within a table view cell. I created an array of all the timers that I need in each cell. When I go to construct the cell and hook up the timer label it gives me the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error. I have tried everything and can not figure out why I keep getting this. The updateTimerLabel method just returns the timerLabel value so I do not see what the issue is. Can someone help me find out how to fix this?

the error is on the `timerLabel`
the timersArray holds an array of all created timers.

Here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimerViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimerViewCell"];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

    tempCell = [timersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = tempCell;
    tempCell = nil;

    cell.timerLabel.text = [cell updateTimerLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

here is the TimerViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Timer.h"

@interface TimerViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel* timerLabel;

    Timer* _timer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* timerLabel;

- (id)initCellWithTimer:(Timer*)timer;
- (IBAction)startTimerButton;
- (NSString*)updateTimerLabel;

@end
```

Comment: Show the header file for TimerViewCell. Also, that line calling `loadNibNamed` doesn't look right. It should return something but you're not setting it to anything.

Comment: A couple of questions: `1)`Does your `cell` subclass implement the `updateTimerLabel` method? `2)`Does your `cell` subclass have a label named `timerLabel`?

Comment: @Aaron I included the TimerViewCell header file

Comment: Got it. Well, I suspect something is going wrong with the `cell` variable, if you're certain that your exception is on the line `cell.timerLabel.text = [cell updateTimerLabel];` Have you debugged to that line to see what `cell` actually is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to allocate cell as follows

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimerViewCell* tempCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimerViewCell"];
    if(tempCell == nil){
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimerViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tempCell = [objects firstObject];
    }
    tempCell.timerLabel.text = [cell updateTimerLabel];

    return tempCell;
}
```

since you are loading cell from xib. You check your outlet connection of your timerLabel.

and also check is your cell pointing to `TimerViewCell`? To check click on cell and check is class like image

[image]

Comment: clean your simulator Quit it and open it again.

Comment: okay I cleared that error but I am still getting the same error. btw `tempCell is already instantiated`

Comment: i get the cell to show now with no error but it says `local declaration of 'tempCell' hides instance variable`

Comment: yes it did. I just changed where you put `tempCell` and put `cell`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening in the following three lines of your code:

```
tempCell = [timersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = tempCell;
    tempCell = nil;
```

You've assigned an element from timersArray to your class variable `tempCell`

Next you've pointed your TimerViewCell instance `cell` to this element.

Finally you remove the pointer that tempCell was holding by assigning it to `nil`, and since `cell` is pointed at `tempCell`, then you are also pointing `cell` at nil

Then in the next line, you attempt to call `updateTimerLabel` on `nil`

```
cell.timerLabel.text = [cell updateTimerLabel];
```

I think you'll have more luck with something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TimerViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TimerViewCell"];
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimerViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimerViewCell"];
    cell.timerLabel.text = [cell updateTimerLabel];
    return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well unlike java in ObjC pointers (direct memory locatioin reference) existing and anything you declare with `*_instance style` will be a pointer.

So when we are assigning one pointer to another they just refer to same location and changing pointer reference to a difreent location (null here) will aparently clean other as well.

`tempCell = [timersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell = tempCell;
tempCell = nil;`

after these three lines even cell will be pointing to a nil. and hence returning nil to cell which is causing crash.

So removing the line `tempCell = nil;` should solve the issue.